# Can I make acrobat reader reload a changed pdf?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

With lots of document readers (okular, xpdf, skim, ghostview) the viewer will reload a document if it is changed. Can acrobat reader do this?

Ubuntu linux 9.04, acroread 8.1.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

acroread does not support it. The PDF reader Evince (Document Viewer), which is installed by default, automatically reloads if the file it is displaying changes.

Answer (score 6):

Current Adobe Reader 9.4.2 allows you to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to reload an opened PDF.

Comment: 2019, Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 2019.012.20034 on Windows does not support Ctrl+R, but I found that File->Revert will reload the file (after a prompt..) and also reopen the Adobe Reader window.

edit. Seems like it only works if modifications have been done (I need to reload files from a dropped network drive.)

Comment: If the file is 'dirtied' by adding e.g. a sticky note this enables the revert option which for me is disabled by default.